# How to change host for all links in mailers without modifying the views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

What I need to do is to include the current host name into all the links generated by mailers.

The problems:

1. Emails are generated in the background and of course do not have access to the current request.
2. I want to avoid modifying any of the templates (updating the mailer class is ok, but not the templates). So that any routing helpers (including ones I do not control, such as devise) still works as expected.

For example, user goes to the restore password on the `abc.example.com`. The email she receives receives should have the link to the `abc.example.com/whatever` and not the `example.com/whatever`.

Similarly, if a user goes to the `other.example.com` and any email is sent to her while she's being using `other.example.com` should point to the same domain name.

I'm pretty sure there should be a way to hook into `action_mailer` to achieve this. So what are those hooks?

Thanks.

Comment: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "abc.example.com" }     i am not entirely sure but you can change your host name configuring like this.

Comment: @sunny1304 that option is global. I need to override that option on a per-email basis depending on what domain a user triggered that email from.